# How to get rid of all of a single character from a string with cut

Tags: bash, cut

I'm trying to get rid of all of the "|" characters and add a space from an input file that is formatted like this:
word|word|number

```
F=$(curl ftp://ip/pub/text.txt)

cut_stuff(){

# this is where I get confused
cut -d"|" -f "1-3"

}

for i in $F; do
echo $i | cut_stuff
done
```

Comment: You want to replace each `|` with a space ? Just use `sed`

Comment: `tr '|' ' '` ? And better to just do `curl ... | cut_stuff` than store curl output in a variable and loop like that.

Comment: Or use bash's built-in substitution: `i="${i//|/ }"` (note: the double-quotes are optional in this particular context, but required in many others).

Comment: @FalseKing : _Remove the `|` and add a space_  ..... Hence `x|5|y` would become `x5y ` (space added at end)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, using `cut`:

```
$ echo 1\|2\|3 | cut -d \| --output-delimiter=" " -f 1-
1 2 3
```